# Streaming h264 realtime 800x600

Tags: video-streaming, resolution, h.264, rtp, mtu

Is it possible to send a video stream using rtp with resolution of 800x600 over the internet in real time?

I've read about MTU limit but i don't know how to accomplish this limit with this resolution even compressing it with h264.

What techniques use popular video chat programs to do this?

I've tried with a lot of compression but I can send only with a resolution of 400x300.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to send a video stream using rtp with resolution of 800x600 over the internet in real time?

Yes.

> I've read about MTU limit but i don't know how to accomplish this limit with this resolution even compressing it with h264.

It doesn't matter: the [H.264 RTP payload format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184) supports fragmtation of larger NAL units to meet MTU contraints. You do need to use the non-interleaved mode which supports fragmentation of NAL units instead single NAL-unit mode where one RTP packet contains one NAL unit.

EDIT:
Your comment changes the context of the question completely.

> Is it possible at 30 fps?

This depends entirely on your definition of 'real-time'. Applications such as video conferencing are considered real-time. However in a scenario such as yours, you have much more critical latency constraints. That's a whole different story and this depends on whether:

- your 'machine' *can* compress the video at 800x600 30fps
- network e.g. wired/wireless, e2e, latency, bw, packet loss, jitter

Also, in such a case, you need to consider what happens when packets or steering information is lost? What are the safety considerations if your machine crashes, etc.? RTP is typically sent over UDP for latency reasons, which means RTP packets can be lost. While you can send it over TCP, in your case, you should absolutely not, as RTP over TCP can result in huge packet arrival delays.

Comment: Really? is it possible at 30fps? because in my free time i'm developing a project where i can drive remotely a little machine with a camera from my pc with a joystick. So is it possible to don't have too delay to make the control stable with a stream 800x600?

Comment: With real-time I mean a maximum delay of 300-500 ms for example.
If it crashes i don't care :)

Comment: The majority of your delay typically comes from the time needed to transmit the packets over the network. In local networks, this should be a couple of milliseconds, which should give you ample time to do retransmissions if desired.